# Integration domains for transformations of a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If the PDF $f(x_1,x_2)$ for RVs $X_1, X_2$ is defined on $ 0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq 1$, and we have 2 transformations of those random variables,

$$U_1 = X_1 + X_2 \ \text{and} \ U_2 = X_2, $$

why is the domain for integration for $U_2$ from

$$ (0, \frac{U_1}{2}) \ \text{and} \ ( \frac{U_1}{2}, 1)?$$

and the domain for $U_1$ is $(0,1)$?

since $X_2 = U_2$ and $U_1 = X_1 + X_2$

$X_1 = U_1 - U_2$
so

$0 \leq U_1 - U_2 \leq U_2 \leq 1$

why wouldn't the domain for $U_2$ be from $U_1 - U_2$ to $1$? I don't see how the integration domain for $U_2$ is divided by two and is split and the more complicated transformation $U_1$ has a simpler domain.

Comment: The inequality you obtained are $U_1 - U_2 \leq U_2$ and $U_2 \leq 1$. Note that the former one is equivalent to $U_2 \geq U_1/2$. As usual the dummy variable inside the integral cannot appear in the integration limits of a definite integral.

Answer (score 1):

> why wouldn't the domain for $\color{purple}{U_2}$ be from $U_1−\color{purple}{U_2}$ to $1$?

Because the integration variable should not appear within the bounds of its own integration.

> why is the domain for integration for $U_2$ from 
>   $$ (0, \frac{U_1}{2}) \ \text{and} \ ( \frac{U_1}{2}, 1)?$$

It should not be.  The support for $U_2$ is $(0;1)$, and the support for $U_1$ is $(0;2)$.

Are you sure you don't mean why is the *joint* support: $0\leq \frac{U_1}2\leq U_2\leq 1$
?

It is because, $U_1-U_2\leq U_2 \iff U_1\leq 2U_2$